# Expectation of function and its derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, expectation

I was wondering if anyone has an idea of what could be said about $f$ given that it satisfies the following inequality:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{\sigma^2}f(x)^2+f'(x)^2+2f(x)f''(x) \right] \geq 0$$
$$x \sim \mathbb{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
Or if I can brake this two smaller rules?

Comment: $z$ doesn't appear in the expectation?

Comment: My bad should have been $x$ not $z$. Thanks!